# Statistics , confidence interval

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I have a sample of $x_i$ where $ x_i =\xi + \eta$ , $\xi \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\eta \sim N(a,1)$ i.i.d. So I need to construct  confidence interval with confidence level $\gamma$ for $\sigma^2$ with unknown $a$.
My attempt is, I used the following statistic : $S^2 = \frac{\sum (x_i - \overline{x})^2}{n-1}$ but I get an interval which could be with negative endpoints.

Comment: $$
\begin{align} & x_i = \xi_i + \eta_i & \text{?} \\ {} \\ & x_i = \xi_i + \eta & \text{?} \\ {} \\ & x_i = \xi + \eta_i & \text{?} \\ {}  \end{align}
$$
Do we have different values of $\eta$ for difference values of $i$? Do we have different values of $\xi$ for different values of $i$? Are observations for different values of $i$ independent?

Comment: Observations are independent, and $\xi$ and $\eta$ are the same for each $x_i$ from sample

Comment: But that means $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are all equal to each other. And what does "i.i.d." mean? It implies something is independent. Which random variables are independent of each other?

Comment: $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent and identically distributed

Comment: @MichaelHardy.  The question makes sense if $x_i=\xi_i+\eta_i$, the $\xi_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, the $\eta_i\sim N(a,1)$ with $\sigma^2$ and $a$ unknown, and given that, all $\xi_i$s and $\eta_i$s are mutually independent.

Comment: @Henry : But it also makes sense if $x_i = \xi_i + \eta,$ where the $\eta$ does not depend on $i.$ And very likely that is what is meant, since the question makes sense that way, in greater degree than if anything else were intended. $\qquad $

Comment: Still , how to solve this problem? When $x_i=\xi_i+\eta_i$

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO : You plainly failed to understand my question. I am well aware that i.i.d. means independent and identically distributed. But $\xi$ and $\eta$ do not both have the same distribution. Typically this might mean that $\xi_1,\ldots,x_n$ are independent of each other and have the same distribution. But you said $\xi$  and $\eta$ are the same for each $x_i,$ which means they are NOT independent.

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO : Did you look at the three alternatives in my first comment above? Currently my best guess is that the second alternative was intended, since the question appears to make more sense that way than with the others.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You have had a suggestion from me and a reply from BeesaFangirl DOTO: $x_i=\xi_i+\eta_i$

Comment: Why the second alternative that you have mentioned is better than the first ?

Comment: Presumably the difficulty is that an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ is $S^2 -1 = \frac{\sum (x_i - \overline{x})^2}{n-1} -1$, but this has a positive probability of being negative even though $\sigma^2$ cannot be negative, and there is a similar issue for confidence intervals.  In fact it does not matter if parts of particular confidence intervals are nonsense, so long as the probability that confidence intervals constructed this way contain the true value is $\gamma$.  But remember that the confidence intervals for $\sigma^2$ are wider than when estimating the variance of the $x_i$s.

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO : Because the first alternative would mean there's nothing in the data to detect which component of $x_i$ comes from $\xi$ and which from $\eta.$ One could just write $x_i \sim \operatorname N(a, 1+ \sigma^2). \qquad$

Comment: I did the same , my first step was $x_i \sim N(a , 1+\sigma^2)$

Comment: @Henry : "it does not matter if parts of particular confidence intervals are nonsense" That is hilariously wrong because it's right. That is the basic objection to the whole idea of confidence intervals. In any practical situation, a "particular" confidence interval is all you've got.

Comment: This leaves another question: Why didn't you write $\xi_i+\eta_i$ if you think that's what was meant?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed this case and I thought that it is clear . That was a misunderstanding

Comment: My suspicion at this point is that you were assigned an exercise in which $x_i = \xi_i + \eta$ was intended, so that $x_i$ changes as $i$ changes, but $\eta$ remains the same as $i$ changes. Otherwise, the purpose of assigning such an exercise and phrasing it in this way escapes me.

Comment: Okay , I see. But I don’t understand how this dramatically change the solution ?

Comment: Before getting into a solution, let us note that the method of moments sometimes yields parameter estimates that are not within the convex hull of the parameter space, so that is not an unknown phenomenon. The method of maximum likelihood never does that, but if you insist on unbiasedness, then you're not doing maximum likelihood. To be continued......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point I am inclined to address the problem as follows, and maybe tomorrow I'll know a more explicit argument in favor of this approach.

You have
\begin{align}
x_i \mid \eta & \sim \operatorname N(0,\sigma^2) \text{ for } i=1,\ldots, n \text{ and } \\
& x_1,\ldots,x_n \text{ are conditionally independent given } \eta, \text{ and} \\[8pt]
\eta & \sim\operatorname N(a,1).
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
(x_i - \eta)\mid \eta \sim \operatorname N(0,\sigma^2).
$$
This expression $\text{“}\operatorname N(0, \sigma^2)\text{''}$ does not depend on $\eta.$ Since the conditional distribution of $x_i-\eta$ does not depend on $\eta,$ it follows that $x_i-\eta$ and $\eta$ are independent, and that the marginal (or "unconditional", if you like) distribution of $x_i-\eta$ is the same as its conditional distribution given $\eta.$ And $x_i-\eta,\,i=1,\ldots,n$ are not only conditionally independent given $\eta,$ but are marginally independent. (Note that $x_i,\,i=1,\ldots,n$ are not marginally independent.)

A well-known result then tells us that
$$
\frac A {\sigma^2} = \frac 1 {\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x\,)^2 \sim \chi^2_{n-1}.
$$
(where $A$ is defined by the equality above). (The reason why $A/\sigma^2$ has this distribution has been posted here as a question and has been answered. There are several ways to do it.)

So one can find numbers $C,D$ for which the following works:
\begin{align}
& \Pr(C < \chi^2_{n-1} <D) = \gamma. \\[8pt]
& \Pr\left( C < \frac A {\sigma^2} < D \right) = \gamma. \\[8pt]
& \Pr\left( \frac A D < \sigma^2 < \frac A C \right) = \gamma.
\end{align}